# Force RTMP streams playing flash to be requested via Proxy Server

Tags: networking, proxy, flash, rtmp

I have a network squid proxy server that all our network traffic is routed through. I have a problem when a RTMP stream is viewed, flash is sending the request directly to the RTMP server and not through my proxy server.

HTTP streamed videos work without any issue and are correctly forwarded through the proxy server.

RTMP does switch down from port 1935 to 443 to 80 if the connection fails, but every one of these connections is made directly to the server with the RTMP stream and not via the proxy server.

Is there any way to force flash to honor the browser proxy settings when it is viewing an RTMP stream?

For completeness I have included a tcpdump of an attempted RTMP connection (IP Addresses have been starred intentionally)

```
 tcpdump -Xlnn host 210.**.***.50
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 96 bytes
09:21:30.537853 IP 192.***.**.43.1722 > 210.**.***.50.1935: S 294800062:294800062(0) win 64240 <mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK>
        0x0000:  4500 0030 a286 4000 8006 dd2f c0a8 5a2b  E..0..@..../..Z+
        0x0010:  d20b 8e32 06ba 078f 1192 4abe 0000 0000  ...2......J.....
        0x0020:  7002 faf0 a283 0000 0204 05b4 0101 0402  p...............
09:21:30.538013 IP 192.***.**.43.1722 > 210.**.***.50.1935: S 294800062:294800062(0) win 64240 <mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK>
        0x0000:  4500 0030 a286 4000 8006 dd2f c0a8 5a2b  E..0..@..../..Z+
        0x0010:  d20b 8e32 06ba 078f 1192 4abe 0000 0000  ...2......J.....
        0x0020:  7002 faf0 a283 0000 0204 05b4 0101 0402  p...............
09:21:30.538050 IP 192.***.**.43.1723 > 210.**.***.50.443: S 3113762863:3113762863(0) win 64240 <mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK>
        0x0000:  4500 0030 a287 4000 8006 dd2e c0a8 5a2b  E..0..@.......Z+
        0x0010:  d20b 8e32 06bb 01bb b998 402f 0000 0000  ...2......@/....
        0x0020:  7002 faf0 0adf 0000 0204 05b4 0101 0402  p...............
09:21:30.538349 IP 192.***.**.43.1723 > 210.**.***.50.443: S 3113762863:3113762863(0) win 64240 <mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK>
        0x0000:  4500 0030 a287 4000 8006 dd2e c0a8 5a2b  E..0..@.......Z+
        0x0010:  d20b 8e32 06bb 01bb b998 402f 0000 0000  ...2......@/....
        0x0020:  7002 faf0 0adf 0000 0204 05b4 0101 0402  p...............
09:21:30.538385 IP 192.***.**.43.1724 > 210.**.***.50.80: S 90552048:90552048(0) win 64240 <mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK>
        0x0000:  4500 0030 a288 4000 8006 dd2d c0a8 5a2b  E..0..@....-..Z+
        0x0010:  d20b 8e32 06bc 0050 0565 b6f0 0000 0000  ...2...P.e......
        0x0020:  7002 faf0 49bb 0000 0204 05b4 0101 0402  p...I...........
09:21:30.538431 IP 192.***.**.43.1724 > 210.**.***.50.80: S 90552048:90552048(0) win 64240 <mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK>
        0x0000:  4500 0030 a288 4000 8006 dd2d c0a8 5a2b  E..0..@....-..Z+
        0x0010:  d20b 8e32 06bc 0050 0565 b6f0 0000 0000  ...2...P.e......
        0x0020:  7002 faf0 49bb 0000 0204 05b4 0101 0402  p...I...........
09:21:33.485085 IP 192.***.**.43.1722 > 210.**.***.50.1935: S 294800062:294800062(0) win 64240 <mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK>
        0x0000:  4500 0030 a289 4000 8006 dd2c c0a8 5a2b  E..0..@....,..Z+
        0x0010:  d20b 8e32 06ba 078f 1192 4abe 0000 0000  ...2......J.....
        0x0020:  7002 faf0 a283 0000 0204 05b4 0101 0402  p...............
09:21:33.485092 IP 192.***.**.43.1722 > 210.**.***.50.1935: S 294800062:294800062(0) win 64240 <mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK>
        0x0000:  4500 0030 a289 4000 8006 dd2c c0a8 5a2b  E..0..@....,..Z+
        0x0010:  d20b 8e32 06ba 078f 1192 4abe 0000 0000  ...2......J.....
        0x0020:  7002 faf0 a283 0000 0204 05b4 0101 0402  p...............
09:21:33.485291 IP 192.***.**.43.1723 > 210.**.***.50.443: S 3113762863:3113762863(0) win 64240 <mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK>
        0x0000:  4500 0030 a28a 4000 8006 dd2b c0a8 5a2b  E..0..@....+..Z+
        0x0010:  d20b 8e32 06bb 01bb b998 402f 0000 0000  ...2......@/....
        0x0020:  7002 faf0 0adf 0000 0204 05b4 0101 0402  p...............
09:21:33.485293 IP 192.***.**.43.1723 > 210.**.***.50.443: S 3113762863:3113762863(0) win 64240 <mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK>
        0x0000:  4500 0030 a28a 4000 8006 dd2b c0a8 5a2b  E..0..@....+..Z+
        0x0010:  d20b 8e32 06bb 01bb b998 402f 0000 0000  ...2......@/....
        0x0020:  7002 faf0 0adf 0000 0204 05b4 0101 0402  p...............
09:21:33.485340 IP 192.***.**.43.1724 > 210.**.***.50.80: S 90552048:90552048(0) win 64240 <mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK>
        0x0000:  4500 0030 a28b 4000 8006 dd2a c0a8 5a2b  E..0..@....*..Z+
        0x0010:  d20b 8e32 06bc 0050 0565 b6f0 0000 0000  ...2...P.e......
        0x0020:  7002 faf0 49bb 0000 0204 05b4 0101 0402  p...I...........
09:21:33.485341 IP 192.***.**.43.1724 > 210.**.***.50.80: S 90552048:90552048(0) win 64240 <mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK>
        0x0000:  4500 0030 a28b 4000 8006 dd2a c0a8 5a2b  E..0..@....*..Z+
        0x0010:  d20b 8e32 06bc 0050 0565 b6f0 0000 0000  ...2...P.e......
        0x0020:  7002 faf0 49bb 0000 0204 05b4 0101 0402  p...I...........
09:21:39.519487 IP 192.***.**.43.1722 > 210.**.***.50.1935: S 294800062:294800062(0) win 64240 <mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK>
        0x0000:  4500 0030 a28d 4000 8006 dd28 c0a8 5a2b  E..0..@....(..Z+
        0x0010:  d20b 8e32 06ba 078f 1192 4abe 0000 0000  ...2......J.....
        0x0020:  7002 faf0 a283 0000 0204 05b4 0101 0402  p...............
09:21:39.519494 IP 192.***.**.43.1722 > 210.**.***.50.1935: S 294800062:294800062(0) win 64240 <mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK>
        0x0000:  4500 0030 a28d 4000 8006 dd28 c0a8 5a2b  E..0..@....(..Z+
        0x0010:  d20b 8e32 06ba 078f 1192 4abe 0000 0000  ...2......J.....
        0x0020:  7002 faf0 a283 0000 0204 05b4 0101 0402  p...............
09:21:39.519549 IP 192.***.**.43.1723 > 210.**.***.50.443: S 3113762863:3113762863(0) win 64240 <mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK>
        0x0000:  4500 0030 a28e 4000 8006 dd27 c0a8 5a2b  E..0..@....'..Z+
        0x0010:  d20b 8e32 06bb 01bb b998 402f 0000 0000  ...2......@/....
        0x0020:  7002 faf0 0adf 0000 0204 05b4 0101 0402  p...............
09:21:39.519550 IP 192.***.**.43.1723 > 210.**.***.50.443: S 3113762863:3113762863(0) win 64240 <mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK>
        0x0000:  4500 0030 a28e 4000 8006 dd27 c0a8 5a2b  E..0..@....'..Z+
        0x0010:  d20b 8e32 06bb 01bb b998 402f 0000 0000  ...2......@/....
        0x0020:  7002 faf0 0adf 0000 0204 05b4 0101 0402  p...............
09:21:39.519585 IP 192.***.**.43.1724 > 210.**.***.50.80: S 90552048:90552048(0) win 64240 <mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK>
        0x0000:  4500 0030 a28f 4000 8006 dd26 c0a8 5a2b  E..0..@....&..Z+
        0x0010:  d20b 8e32 06bc 0050 0565 b6f0 0000 0000  ...2...P.e......
        0x0020:  7002 faf0 49bb 0000 0204 05b4 0101 0402  p...I...........
09:21:39.519587 IP 192.***.**.43.1724 > 210.**.***.50.80: S 90552048:90552048(0) win 64240 <mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK>
        0x0000:  4500 0030 a28f 4000 8006 dd26 c0a8 5a2b  E..0..@....&..Z+
        0x0010:  d20b 8e32 06bc 0050 0565 b6f0 0000 0000  ...2...P.e......
        0x0020:  7002 faf0 49bb 0000 0204 05b4 0101 0402  p...I...........
```

Comment: Are you using adobe's flashplayer, or one of the open source replacements? (if a replacement, which one?)

Comment: Adobes flash player

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround, but it appears to be windows specific. The software they mention is shareware, and windows-only. http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f131/different-proxy-settings-for-flash-player-397364.html

Basically, this is a bug that needs to be reported to Adobe. There is no way to make it use your proxy of it's own volition.

(For the record, I have used the software they mention and it's a horrible pile of... badness)